# While loops always returns true in java

Tags: java, spring, loops, while-loop

My while loop returns true regardless of if he input is true or not. So it check if the director exists using the id method in dao. The while loop should end once this changes to false and the id does not exist. id starts at 1 for first iteration. d F Name and d S Name take in the first id of 1. If the current director names aren't equal to the new director being created, it should increment id by 1. If they don't not match, it should simply return "true". If its the else option then that
should just increment id by 1 again and go back into the loop. This should continue until the first Id that does not exist, or a duplicate name is found.

It seems to me that it isn't running if statement conditional in the very first if statement and skipping straight to the if statement nested inside the first. I've tried chaging around the loop, using do... while(), only if statements and while statements without ifs and no changes.

```
This is the loop I am working on. 
   

public boolean checkDirectorNameIsNotDuplicate(Director director) {
        int id = 1;
        String dFName;
        String dSName;
            while(directorDao.existsById(id)==true) {
                dFName = directorDao.getDirectorFirstNameById(id);
                dSName = directorDao.getDirectorSurnameById(id);
                if (!director.getDirectorFirstName().equals(dFName) && !director.getDirectorSurname().equals(dSName)){// if directorFirstName is not equal to dFName AND directorSurname is not equal to dsname
                        id++; //move to next Id
                        System.out.println(id);
                        }
                else {
                            if (director.getDirectorFirstName().equals(dFName) && director.getDirectorSurname().equals(dSName)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                id++;
                            }
                    }
                }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: You never need to say `== true`, and correct indentation makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: if a director with id=1 doesn't exist, the program will never enter the while. In the same way when there's not a director with id =x it will exit

Comment: From the standpoint of reality a firstName/lastName combination is rarely unique in any organization of any size. And names are very personal. While I was working for Penn State, I would have brought a complaint against anything that required me to enter a first name (I use my first initial and my middle and last names).

Comment: Thank you. I am actually studying so have some requirements that I need to learn how to do which is why it is in particular ways! The name being split and then checking if it works is one of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing logically, something in your if-else statements are redundant. It is better to remove some statements and change to the following code which is just made simple modification from yours.

In addition, your variable `id` does not have an end condition, which could lead to an infinite loop.

```java
public boolean checkDirectorNameIsNotDuplicate(Director director) {
    int id = 1;
    String dFName;
    String dSName;
    while(directorDao.existsById(id)) {
        dFName = directorDao.getDirectorFirstNameById(id);
        dSName = directorDao.getDirectorSurnameById(id);

        if (director.getDirectorFirstName().equals(dFName) && director.getDirectorSurname().equals(dSName)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            id++;
            System.out.println(id);
            
            // add condition here to void an infinite loop
            if (/*something to do with id*/) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This helped sort it! I just had to change around the condition in my controller that called up the page but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the entire metohd. As written in my comment, if a director with id=1 doesn't exist, your while never enters. In the same way if you have ids till x-1, id x is not associated to any director and from x+1 on you have some directors (i.e. if ids are not all contiguos), the last one will be never checked.
What i would like to do is:

- retrieve all directors in a list with a new method in directorDao, say `directorDao.list()`
- iterate over the list.

Code sample

```
public boolean checkDirectorNameIsNotDuplicate(Director director) {
    int id = 1;
    String dFName;
    String dSName;
    List<Director> directors=directorDao.list(); //new method in directorDao
    if (directors!=null){
       for(Director d:directors){
           if (director.getDirectorFirstName().equals(d.getDirectorFirstName()) && director.getDirectorSurname().equals(d.getDirectorSurname())) {
              return true;
           } //closes if

       }// closes for
    return false;
    } //end method
```

Moreover, why don't you make the check directly in SQL, something like adding in the dao a method `checkDirector(name, surname)` which returns true if sa director with name and surname is found ? The query to do is very easy.